# Performance issue while writing DF to file using maxRecordsPerFile

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am processing around 10 days of data which I am partitioning based on date and using the df write option `maxRecordsPerFile`.

100% of the cluster resource is used while the data is read but as soon as suffle write starts 99% of the cores are removed and only one core is used with 1-2% of memory .

How to overcome the issue so that my cluster is fully utilized?

** In case I am not wrong if I do PartitionBy on Date than only the data for that specific date should be brought to one core. i.e 10 days of data should be running on 10 cores if using PartitionBy, however on usage of  `maxRecordsPerFile` all 10 days of data is pulled to only one core.

Comment: Can you share, how much data do you have for 10 days?

Comment: around 500GB which we are joining with another set of 200 GB

Comment: So after join how much data, you are saving to disk?

Comment: there is no filtering. around 700GB writing to HDFS.